# Is this constraint convex in an optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, cvxpy

<sub>[Crossposted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77593676) on Stack Overflow</sub>

---

I have an optimization problem with the following inequality constraint

$$e^{x_n} \leq B \log _2\left(1+\frac{e^{\rho_n} g_n^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \exp \left(\rho_i\right) g_i^2+\sigma^2}\right)$$

where $\rho_n$ and $x_n$ are among the decision variables and $B$,  $\sigma$ and $g$  are constant. Is this constraint convex?

I tried to write the Python code of the optimization problem using the CVXPY library and the Mosek solver, but the above clause causes a `DCP Rule Error`.

Comment: The question was whether the constraint is convex or non-convex. I did not say it is non-convex!
The constraint can be checked alone because the decision variables and constants are declared.

Comment: It is obviously not convex. Just check the 2 variable case $n=1$ with all constants equal one. Then the function $g(x,\rho) = e^x - \log(1+e^\rho)$ is a sum of a convex and concave function. But even if it was, CVXPY can still give you a DCP error.